# 1and1 SSL Certificate with Heroku App

Tags: ssl, heroku

Could someone walk me through how to set up the SSL Certificate that I bought through 1and1 with my Heroku application and my 1and1 domain?

I am able to set it up and it stays active for a few minutes but then goes back to saying unsecured.

Let's call my domain `harrison.com`. I have a subdomain `www.harrison.com`. Let's say my heroku app is `harrison.herokuapp.com`.

What i'm currently doing is changing `harrison.com` to redirect to `www.harrison.com` and then changing that cname to `harrison.herokussl.com` which is currently not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have finally solved this.

I continued to redirect my TLD to the subdomain `www`, then then set the CNAME of the subdomain to `www.my_app_name.com.herokudns.com`. After that, I combined the server certificate (obtained from my DNS, 1and1), with the immediate certficate (also from 1and1) into 1 file with a `.pem` extension.

Finally, I uploaded the `.pem` certificate and the `.key` key to Heroku.

Comment: Can you detail what you have done ?